# Touch scrolling animation for list of images in iOS

Tags: animation, ios6, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uianimation

[image]My requirement is to display the list of images in horizantal way.when I touch the image it is  moved to side and the next image is comes to front.In this way I need to move images side by side.Then is there any method to scroll the list of images?or Can I go for any type of animation ?

In this way images are to be placed and moved.Please suggest me how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a working module of cover flow.....

try transformation on layers which allows 3D transformation using....

```
-(void) rotateView3D:(UIView *)myView:(CGFloat)angle
{

    CATransform3D affinAndScaleTransform;
    if (angle==30.0f||angle==-30.0f)
    {
        affinAndScaleTransform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9f, 0.9f));
    }
    else
    {
        affinAndScaleTransform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f));
    }
    CALayer *layer = myView.layer;

//    layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
//    layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;

    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
    rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, angle * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    [layer setTransform:CATransform3DConcat(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, affinAndScaleTransform)];
}
```

to scroll the views add gesture .......

for left gesture use some thig like this ........

```
{
    UIView * view0 = [self.view viewWithTag:-1111];
    UIView * view1 = [self.view viewWithTag:1111];
    UIView * view2 = [self.view viewWithTag:2222];
    UIView * view3 = [self.view viewWithTag:3333];
    UIView * view4 = [self.view viewWithTag:4444];

    [view4 setFrame:self.rect0];

    int preViewNo = self.leftProduct-1;
    if (preViewNo<0)preViewNo=self.productArray.count-1;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^
     {
         [view0 setFrame:self.rect1];
         [self rotateView3D:view0 : 30.0f];

         [view1 setFrame:self.rect2];
         [self rotateView3D:view1 : 0.0f];

         [view2 setFrame:self.rect3];
         [self rotateView3D:view2 : -30.0f];

         [view3 setFrame:self.rect4];
         [self rotateView3D:view4 : 0.0f];

     }];

    [self setdescriptionView:view0 :[self.productArray objectAtIndex:preViewNo]];

    [view0 setTag:1111];
    [view1 setTag:2222];
    [view2 setTag:3333];
    [view3 setTag:4444];
    [view4 setTag:-1111];

    self.currentProduct--;
    self.rightProduct--;
    self.leftProduct--;
    if (self.currentProduct < 0) self.currentProduct=self.productArray.count-1;
    if (self.rightProduct < 0) self.rightProduct=self.productArray.count-1;
    if (self.leftProduct < 0) self.leftProduct=self.productArray.count-1;


}
```

on right gesture recognizer use some thing like this.......

```
{
    UIView * view0 = [self.view viewWithTag:-1111];
    UIView * view1 = [self.view viewWithTag:1111];
    UIView * view2 = [self.view viewWithTag:2222];
    UIView * view3 = [self.view viewWithTag:3333];
    UIView * view4 = [self.view viewWithTag:4444];

    [view0 setFrame:self.rect4];

    int nextViewNo = self.rightProduct+1;
    if (nextViewNo>=self.productArray.count)nextViewNo=0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^
     {
         [view4 setFrame:self.rect3];
         [self rotateView3D:view4 : -30.0f];

         [view3 setFrame:self.rect2];
         [self rotateView3D:view3 : 0.0f];

         [view2 setFrame:self.rect1];
         [self rotateView3D:view2 : 30.0f];

         [view1 setFrame:self.rect0];
         [self rotateView3D:view1 : 0.0f];

     }];

    [self setdescriptionView:view4 :[self.productArray objectAtIndex:nextViewNo]];

    [view0 setTag:4444];
    [view1 setTag:-1111];
    [view2 setTag:1111];
    [view3 setTag:2222];
    [view4 setTag:3333];

    self.currentProduct++;
    self.rightProduct++;
    self.leftProduct++;
    if (self.currentProduct >= self.productArray.count) self.currentProduct=0;
    if (self.rightProduct >= self.productArray.count) self.rightProduct=0;
    if (self.leftProduct >= self.productArray.count) self.leftProduct=0;
}
```

for some technical reason i have to make custom coverflow....

you can also try this .....

[icarousal](http://code4app.net/ios/iCarousel-for-Cover-Flow/4f87d2db06f6e79d32000000)

Comment: Thank you Nirav,Ya I tried the icarousal.But actually my requirement is to display the table views of cover flow not the imageviews.So I tried this simply by setting label and button.It works well.but I didn't understand Where I have to write the code for setting target for the button.Please give me suggestion.

Comment: Dear Rani, Your most welcome, i had the similar problem i need to display UIViews in coverflow. These UIViews contains imageview and some labels so i have made this custom cover flow. here i have posted sample code of that custom coverflow. Using this custom coverflow you can do any thing. this coverflow uses uiview instead of UIImageview so you can place any control you want. If you have any problem using this code please feel free to ask..

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem .I found the sample example in this link.http://code4app.net/category/scrollview